# Seek a quick way to bring standard order back to original after Complement

Tags: list-manipulation

the `Complement` gives result in standard order.

But that's not what I want. I want it to keep the original order.

say I have a list

```
list = {8, 3, 6, 4, 2, 5, 7};
```

and

```
compli = Complement[list, {3, 6, 2}]
```

gives

```
{4, 5, 7, 8}
```

But I want

```
{8, 4, 5, 7}
```

I write the following code to bring it back to the original order

```
Reap[If[MemberQ[compli, #], Sow[#]] & /@ list][[2, 1]]
```

I don't know whether it is good or not. Maybe there is more elegant way to do this.

Finally, I must say I just don't understand why `Complement` is designed to give standard order. If I want standard order, I can simply use `Sort`. And now things got more complicated than it should be.

Comment: @PinguinDirk, great, now you are telling us, after all this hard work :)

Comment: @Nasser: sorry, I am on weekend-mode :) And actually, not sure if it's an exact dupe - but close enough I'd say

Comment: @PinguinDirk OK, I admit my question is a duplicate. Why I can't find the duplicate before I post the question? Have you seen that question before or you just searched and find duplicates?

Comment: @matheorem I guess this is one of the points of having a coherent community. Someone would remember that the question was asked before (often because that person either asked or answered that question), and point it out. It is not always possible to tell in advance (or even after serious search effort) whether the question has been asked before, even for the most active users. This is just a fact of life.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[list, x_ /; FreeQ[{3, 6, 2}, x]]
```

> {8, 4, 5, 7}

Answer (score 1):

List in Mathematica is like a mathematical set. Hence no order is implied. But you can use `SortBy`

```
list = {8, 3, 6, 4, 2, 5, 7};
compli = Complement[list, {3, 6, 2}]
(*{4, 5, 7, 8}*)
SortBy[compli, (First@Position[list, #]) &]

 (* {8, 4, 5, 7} *)
```

Another example: (just to verify)

```
list = {8, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 5, 7, 7, 5, 5};
compli = Complement[list, {3, 6, 2}]
(*  {4, 5, 7, 8} *)
SortBy[compli, (First@Position[list, #]) &]
{8, 5, 4, 7}
```

Comment: I'd say list isn't like set. Thats why `{1, 2} != {2, 1}`.

Comment: @Kuba Only if set is not constrained to be ordered.

Comment: @Kuba, but you need to use the correct comparing operator then for comparing sets :)  You are using an operator `=` whose semantics are not defined for use with true Mathematical sets. That is why I said "like" a mathematical set. But for this for another place to discuss I suppose.

Comment: Yes, you are right. :) @Blackbird I was taught that ordered set is not a set but series. But I admit that is a material for a long talk, here offtopic :)

Comment: @Kuba, it is a list (for ordered, not series). This is actually an important topic, since some CAS systems support both a set and a list as basic data types. Here is Maple page on this for example: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/MapleSim/view.aspx?path=set , so this sort of thing can be important in some applications...I remember this was talked about before at mathgroup.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[list, FreeQ[{3, 6, 2}, #] &]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
Fold[DeleteCases, list, {3, 6, 2}]
```

> ```
> {8, 4, 5, 7}
> ```

Comment: Not sure that `Fold` has any advantages over `DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ {3, 6, 2}]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch me too, I just like `Fold` :) so if it does not matter.. :)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch why do you delete your answer? I was just asking you what do you mean by "direct way"

Comment: @matheorem I deleted because it was a duplicate